# How to Validate string Expression using RegExp?

Tags: c++, regex, qt, validation, qt5

I have a string "\**03**COUNTER\TIME_NOW"

Valid Range of min to Max allowed for COUNTER prefix is 01 to 09

**Example:**

> "\02COUNTER\TIME_NOW":   Valid
>
> "\10COUNTER\TIME_NOW":   Not valid
>
> "\00COUNTER\TIME_NOW":   Not valid
>
> "\88COUNTER\TIME_NOW":   Not valid

Can some one give how to get state of valid/Not valid using regexpression?

Comment: `\\0[0-9]COUNTER\\TIME_NOW`

Comment: It is actually \\0[1-9]COUNTER\\TIME_NOW

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\\0[1-9]COUNTER\\TIME_NOW` is the regex you are looking for.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>

int main ()
{
    if (std::regex_match ("\\02COUNTER\\TIME_NOW", std::regex("\\\\0[1-9]COUNTER\\\\TIME_NOW") ))
        std::cout << "valid\n";
    else
        std::cout << "invalid\n";

    if (std::regex_match ("\\10COUNTER\\TIME_NOW", std::regex("\\\\0[1-9]COUNTER\\\\TIME_NOW") ))
        std::cout << "valid\n";
    else
        std::cout << "invalid\n";

    if (std::regex_match ("\\00COUNTER\\TIME_NOW", std::regex("\\\\0[1-9]COUNTER\\\\TIME_NOW") ))
        std::cout << "valid\n";
    else
        std::cout << "invalid\n";

    if (std::regex_match ("\\88COUNTER\\TIME_NOW", std::regex("\\\\0[1-9]COUNTER\\\\TIME_NOW") ))
        std::cout << "valid\n";
    else
        std::cout << "invalid\n";

    return 0;
}
```

prints

```
valid
invalid
invalid
invalid
```